# Any other way to solve $ \int\frac{1}{1+\tan x} \,dx $?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int\frac{1}{1+\tan x} \,dx
$$

One method to solve is to use $ \tan{2 \theta} = \frac{2\tan{\theta}}{1-\tan^2{\theta}}  $

Second is by reducing integrand in terms of $ \sin x $ and  $\cos x$

Third is to put $\tan x = t $, But it is same as the first method.

Is there any other way to solve this ?

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of ways to solve this, you can even use the substitution $\tan x = u$.
This would get you an Integral like this:

$$\int \frac 1 {(1+u^2)(1+u)}du$$ which using partial fraction can get you to

$$\frac 1 2 \int \frac {1-u} {1+u^2}+ \frac 1 {1+u} $$

Re-arranging, substituting and simplifying it a bit would get you the result:

$$\frac {x+\ln(\sin x+ \cos x)} 2 + C$$

Answer (score 3):

With the use of $1+\tan^2 x=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x},$ rewrite $$\int\frac{1}{1+\tan x} \,dx= \int\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{(1+\tan^2 x)(1+\tan x)}\,dx=\int \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(1+t)},$$ then use partial fractions.

Comment: This is another way to write $ \tan x = t$, but yes, good one.

Comment: My smartphone doesn't show simultaneous activities of other contributors while I am editing, so I edited similar solution as you ...now the yours and the mine complete each other :) (+1)

Comment: Indeed they do :)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to note that $\dfrac{1}{1+\tan x}=\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}$, so let
$$
I_1:=\int\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}\,\mathrm{d}x,\quad I_2:=\int\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
It is obvious that $I_1+I_2=x+C_+$ and $I_1-I_2=\log(\cos x+\sin x)+C_-$.  Adding and divide by $2$ gives $I_1=\frac{1}{2}\left[x+\log(\cos x+\sin x)\right]+C$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $$\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}$$ and use the Substitution
$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\frac{2}{1+\tan x} =\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{1+\tan x}+1-\tan x.$$
Then
\begin{align}2\int\frac{1}{1+\tan x}dx&=\int\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{1+\tan x}dx+\int 1dx-\int\tan x\, dx\\
&=\int\frac{(1+\tan x)'}{1+\tan x}dx+\int 1dx+\int\frac{(\cos x)'}{\cos x}\, dx\\
&=\ln(|1+\tan x|)+x+\ln(|\cos x|)+c.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac1{1+\tan x}=\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}$$

Let $\cos x=a(\cos x+\sin x)+b\dfrac{d(\cos x+\sin x)}{dx}$

$=\cos x\cdot(a+b)+\sin x\cdot(a-b)$

Set $a-b=0,a+b=1$